# why does the `as` keyword used to remap types break docs

Tags: typescript, types, default

i'm extracting a type from an object and i'd like for the type keys to have the same docs as the object, here's a much shorter version of what i'm trying to achieve:

```js
/** this is the object to extract type from */
const obj = {
  // the following should show when i use `as` inside of type creation
  /**  this is a id */
  id: undefined as string,
  /**  this is a num */
  num: 22 as number
};
```

and here's the types:

```js
// extract keys with string type only
type UseAsKeyword<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as Extract<T[K], string> extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
};
type NoAsKeyword<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };
type ObjWithAs = UseAsKeyword<typeof obj>;
type ObjNoAs = NoAsKeyword<typeof obj>;
```

usage:

```js
// this one doesn't show docs mentioned in `obj`
const testWithAs: ObjWithAs = { id: "hello" };
// this one shows docs mentioned in `obj`
const testNoAs: ObjNoAs = { id: "hello", num: 22 };
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  // for all node depandant environments like Vite
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
}
```

screenshots from typescript playground: 
[no docs on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A7JS.png) 
[docs on hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDdXW.png)

I'd like to use the `as` keyword and maintain property/key docs, if this is not possible, then what's the alternative to remapping keys but maintain docs?

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#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)

Comment: Please show a running example specifying. I've copied your code to TypeScript Playground and added it to your answer but it's hard to see what you're asking since the code you have has errors.  It's not clear what you mean by "not breaking docs inheritance/reference". You should explain with simpler words what you expected and what actually happened.

Comment: Not sure what's the exact reason but seems that wrapping it with `Omit` at the top level solves the issue `type UseAsKeyword<T> = Omit<{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}, keyof {[K in keyof T as Extract<T[K], string> extends never ? K : never]: T[K]}>;`. Let me know if this suits you. Haven't tried if a simpler approach exists.

Comment: The docs wouldn't be there without `as` either. You need to document the type and not the `obj` variable.

Comment: @JuanMendes you needed to turn off `strictNullChecks` under tsconfig, i changed it. now hover over `id` key in `testWithAs` and in `testNoAs`, you should see no docs in the first one.

Comment: @WiktorZychla i cannot use `Omit<>` because it misbehaves under `strictNullChecks` config setting, but i'll explore more on that path

Comment: @kelly i modified the example link by JuanMendes to demonstrate my question better, please take a look.

Comment: @eslamsharif The instructions on how to reproduce the problem should be in the question itself, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

apparently using the `as` keyword populates a new type detached from the passed one, so the only way to keep the type persistent is to use the `Omit<>` utility type as suggested by @WiktorZychla. 
so the following type would be changed to:

```js
// remapping keys with `as` directly, breaks docs reference
type UseAsKeyword<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as Extract<T[K], string> extends never ? never : K]: T[K];
};
// omiting keys remapped with `as`, maintains docs reference
type UseAsKeywordOmit<T> = Omit<
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}, 
  keyof {
  [K in keyof T as Extract<T[K], string> extends never ? K : never]: T[K];
}>;
```

usage [Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIBcAsEsGdwKtApuA9gIwFaoMaRQbioAekATgIaFQCeADugGaUYC24IwAUPhgB28IthzgAvOADevcOGDAUrDABtVGAO6xBAc3DxoGAK6qAJgaObwmtIKThj8dAANq8F0mGwz6DCwZmcHxKVGpIWCE5BTB5GGRkaiQLHmifAC5HQV8WHVQLdyyAa0Ete0KRSh1dABpo0AgUBMQkwWMuVPk2jkyAJl7wQu6sVEpeAF8Abl5eRXBQjmpGRmrwItR6RG0YcDcPcDNYUMJVel5IJnQAVWcAQXgAaQ3NDEozAB4AFQA+SRlogDaDy8aw2-nAn0GiAAohQaIQvkCALo1AxUaq-ciQVDZRCCVAAN1G4AA-OB8UTKOBMg8kZlPsjplMZnNOLAInpQZt5qhFst8jZ2dBdu4XOdLuAbqh7k96C83gB5Djsr6-KRKlXRaRAkHrejgz50iHI8ao6J68GyeQ6nRcg1Q8Cwqi0SCI2moyoY0gUHFmPGE4lk4GZCmjI0M2lM77TFlKIyUzAJnyo-XGADk6gMqHQpQOGHw8H4QhEUFQIgA6kL7pkpTLnq8PhdmOCxGqZMlMgAiNDqDCd8BTcCx8Dx4kYJNmFMmDOqLPoMz5wsCYREbEVqvwDWQGt3R71xXK11N1At3Bt6Qd8Dd1C9-uDoA):

```js
// hover over id, you'll see no docs reference
const testWithAs: UseAsKeyword<typeof obj> = { id: "hello" }; 

// hover over id, you'll see docs reference
const testWithAsOmit: UseAsKeywordOmit<typeof obj> = { id: "hello" };
```

now this introduces a couple of hassles like:

- more `Omit` keyword,curly and angled brackets will have to be written and it'll get uglier the longer the type is.(check out `DeepVoid` [at this gist](https://gist.github.com/neod3v/57a4bed07d57d57e8a45c91dcc7b4e53))
- the logic has to be inversed to exclude what's not needed instead of including what's needed, which sometimes gets tricky and is not as simple.
  but in the end, it gets the job done.

Comment: Just to your information, in future, if a comment suits you, please let the comment author know and ask them to make an answer of that comment so that you accept the answer and people get credited. This answer looks like you accepted my suggestion but rather than letting me know, you made an answer by yourself. Regards.

Comment: @WiktorZychla how do i let you know?, i already tagged you in the answer. plus, i also did alot of research on the matter and your solution (which i found a while back) doesn't really answer the question instead it's just a workaround the `as` keyword, but thanks i appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, for some reason tagging me in your answer didn't work. I got back there just because I was curious if a better suggestion was provided and thus I've found your answer. I hope the shorter version I posted in a separate answer suits you even better. Regards.

Comment: @WiktorZychla cool thanks, i would upvote your answer but i'm not allowed to do that yet so if you may upvote mine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rather verbose definition I suggested in a comment

```
type UseAsKeywordOmit<T> = Omit<
  {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}, 
  keyof {
  [K in keyof T as Extract<T[K], string> extends never ? K : never]: T[K];
}>;
```

can be simplified to

```
type UseAsKeywordOmit<T> = Omit<T, keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? never : K]: T[K]; }>;
```

This is because the

```
{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}
```

is obviously just

```
T
```

and the `Exclude` can be inlined here so it's not needed.

I hope this shorter version suits you even better.

Comment: thanks!, for a simple example that does it just fine but for more complex types  we'll need to rewrite `T` maybe omit some keys from it as well as using `Exclude` or `Extract` for multi type properties.